# Using reqMktDepth for trading in R

Tags: r, real-time, trading, ibrokers

I am trying to test an intraday trading strategy using R, and I found the `IBrokers` API package that sends orders to Interactive Brokers TWS platrform, which would be perfect for me.  Unfortunately my programming skills aren´t good enought to get the job done!

In any case, my strategy would be looking at the market depth placing orders above and below the market at prices that depend on the size of the bids and ask.

From what I have learned until now, I beleive the `reqMktDepth` function creates an infinite loop that updates the bids and asks through the `twsCALLBACK`.

What I tried to do is to create a function, called `callback.intraday` that does my trading strategy and subsequently calls the `twsCALLBACK`, from what I understood I should use the reqMktDepth and use my function inside it.

Below is the code of my function:

```
callback.intraday <- function(numoflots=50, file=f, lenghtofdepth=10, target=0.30, mintick=0.01){
  csvfile <- na.omit(read.delim(file=file, sep=" ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names=c("date", "time", "NA", "NA", "NA", "position", "operation", "bid.ask", "price", "size", "NA")))
  csvfile <- csvfile[1:(lenghtofdepth*2),]
  csvfile <- csvfile[order(csvfile$position),]

  #0 is ask, 1 is bid
  askdepth <- biddepth<- 0  
  for (i in 1:nrow(csvfile)){

    if(!csvfile$position[i]==0 && csvfile$bid.ask[i]==1 && askdepth<numoflots){
      askdepth <- askdepth+as.numeric(csvfile$size[i])
      buyprice <- as.numeric(csvfile$price[i])-mintick
    }

    if(!csvfile$position[i]==0 && csvfile$bid.ask[i]==0 && biddepth<numoflots){
      biddepth <- biddepth+as.numeric(csvfile$size[i])
      sellprice <- as.numeric(csvfile$price[i])+mintick
    }


  }


  #entering buyside
  #ids <- as.numeric(reqIds(tws))
  #entorder <- twsOrder(ids,"BUY", "1", "STPLMT", lmtPrice = buyprice, auxPrice = buyprice+2*mintick)
  #ids <- as.numeric(reqIds(tws))
  #tarorder <- twsOrder(ids,"SELL", "1", "LMT", lmtPrice = buyprice+target)
  #placeOrder(twsconn=tws, Contract=security, Order=entorder)
  #placeOrder(twsconn=tws, Contract=security, Order=tarorder)

  #entering sellside
  #ids <- as.numeric(reqIds(tws))
  #entorder <- twsOrder(ids,"SELL", "1", "STPLMT", lmtPrice = sellprice, auxPrice = sellprice+2*mintick)
  #ids <- as.numeric(reqIds(tws))
  #tarorder <- twsOrder(ids,"BUY", "1", "LMT", lmtPrice = sellprice-target)
  #placeOrder(twsconn=tws, Contract=security, Order=entorder)
  #placeOrder(twsconn=tws, Contract=security, Order=tarorder)

  twsCALLBACK(twsCon = tws)
}
```

I still haven´t tested the sending the orders into the market since I am still stuck with the loop.

Below is the code that I am running and getting an "unused arguments" error.

```
    require(IBrokers)
tws <- twsConnect(port=7496)
isConnected(tws)
symb <- "CL"
exchange <- "NYMEX"
expiry <- "201804"
f <- "C:/Users/augus/Dropbox/Trading/R/Trading/Intraday/depth.csv"
contract <- twsFuture(symbol=symb, exch=exchange, expiry=expiry)

reqMktDepth(tws, contract, file=f, CALLBACK = callback.intraday)
```

Thanks for the help

Augusto

Comment: Did you backtest your strategy before trying to implement it? Level II trading was viable 20 years ago. What you see there now is mostly HFT/market maker 'traps'

Comment: that is what I am testing.